# Set currency values in new VBA Class module

Tags: vba, class, ms-access, currency

I created a class module in Access VBA for stock price information.  For reasons I can't figure out, when I try to assign currency values in my tests, my instance always are 0.  Other data types (strings and dates) seem to work fine.  Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the relevant section from my class module:

```
Public Property Let Price(ByVal dollar As Currency)
    pPrice = dollar
End Property

Public Property Get Price() As Currency
    dollar = pPrice
End Property

Public Property Let Peak(ByVal amt As Currency)
    pAmt = amt
End Property

Public Property Get Peak() As Currency
    amt = pAmt
End Property
```

When I run this test:

```
Sub TestStock()

Dim st As Stock

Set st = New Stock

st.Symbol = "AMD"
st.CreateDt = #1/10/2019#
st.Name = "Advanced Micro Devices"
st.Industry = Information_Technology
st.Price = 19
st.Peak = 24


Debug.Print st.Symbol, st.CreateDt, st.Name, st.IndustryText, st.Price, st.Peak

Set st = Nothing    
End Sub
```

My results are always the same:

**AMD  1/10/2019  Advanced Micro Devices  Information_Technology   0   0**

What trick am I missing to assign values to currency data types?

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` on top and you will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the `Get()` method of your property.

```
Public Property Get Price() As Currency
    dollar = pPrice '<-- wrong, dollar means nothing in this context
    Price = pPrice '<-- right, that's the property you want to Get
End Property
```

For the property `Price`, for example, `dollar` is just a local variable you used in the `Set()` method. However, once you go out of the method set, that variable is trashed by the garbage collector and becomes `0` (default value).
Hence, when you try to get it back, you get the current value of it (which is `0`).

I guess you're doing it right for the other properties, but since you didn't share the code I can't confirm.

Someone suggested you in the comment to put `Option Explicit` on top of your module, it would help to avoid this kind of mistake (in your case, the variable `dollar` wouldn't be defined in the context of `Public Property Get Price() As Currency`and so you would get a compile error).

Comment: You were absolutely right about the Get and dollar confusion.  Wasn't paying enough attention, and yes, I should use Option Explicit!  Thank you!